# Python3_Pygame ウィンドウが最前面にこない

Tags: python3, pygame

## ウィンドウが最前面に表示されない

最近Python3とPygameでゲーム制作を始めました．ところが最初からつまずいており，ネット上で調べたり書籍を買って調べても全く解決できません．試したものは単純に，ウィンドウを表示させるだけのものです．

プログラムを実行するとウィンドウが最前面に表示されず，他の画面を全て隠してからではないと見えません．エラーなども全く出ていないので，もしかしたらこういうものなのでしょうか．
[image: 必ずターミナルの後ろに]

このせいで必ず全面の画面を最小化する必要があります．ちなみにコードは参考文献にある[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8xNA.png)を使っています．(PyGameに限らず，turtleなどで図形を描画する際にも同じことが起こります．)

#### 環境

macOS Sierra(10.12.6)
Python(3.6.1) #pyenvでインストールしたもの
Pygame(1.9.3)

## コード

```
#_*_coding:utf-8_*_                                                                                                                     
#ウィンドウを表示する                                                                                                                   
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() #pygameの初期化                                                                                                           
SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300)) #ウィンドウの大きさ                                                                       
pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame") #タイトルバー                                                                                      

# mainループ                                                                                                                            
def main():
    while True:
        SURFACE.fill((0,0,0)) #ウィンドウの背景色                                                                                       
        #イベントの取得                                                                                                                 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit() #閉じるボタンが押されたらプログラムを終了                                                                 
                sys.exit
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

別に最前面にこないものというならそれでもいいのですが(手間なだけなので)，理由がわからずモヤモヤしているので，分かるかたがいらっしゃいましたらご回答よろしくお願いします．

#### 参考文献

1, 田中賢一郎 (2017) 「ゲームを作りながら楽しく学べるPythonプログラミング」 インプレスR&D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pygame.init() #pygameの初期化                                                                                                           
SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300)) #ウィンドウの大きさ                                                                       
pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame") #タイトルバー                                                                                      

SURFACE.fill((0,0,0)) #一回                                                                                    
pygame.display.flip()

# mainループ                                                                                                                            
def main():
    while True:
        #イベントの取得                                                                                                                 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit() #閉じるボタンが押されたらプログラムを終了                                                                 
                sys.exit
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

http://westplain.sakuraweb.com/translate/pygame/Display.cgi

> `pygame.display.flip` display Surface全体を更新して画面に描写します

Comment: ありがとうございます．解決できました．